# Create a HttpWebRequest for a http://user:password@doamin/query Url

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I need to send a HttpWebRequest to a url with basic inline credentials as follows:

```
http://user:password@doamin/query
```

I've tried setting the Url as is, but it didnt seem to pass the credentials (got 403).
Tried setting the Credentials property of HttpWebRequest:

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("username","pasword")
```

And removing them from the url (resulting in `http://domain/query`) but still got the same result (403).

Using the Url directly from any browser succeeded so the credentials are Ok.

What am I missing?

**[UPDATE - ANSWER]**
Here's the code that worked for me:

```
string credentials = "username:password";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(formattedUrl);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials)));
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 2):

First you create your creds class:

```
NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Add it your Creds Cache:

```
CredentialCache credsCache = new CredentialCache();
```

```
// NOTE! THE PROTOCOL is needed in Uri (e.g. http://)
credsCache.Add(new Uri("proto://www.foo.com"), "Basic", myCred);
```

Now you can do a web request:

```
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("www.foo.com");
```

Then set the wr.Credentials to the credsCache:

```
wr.Credentials = credsCache;
```

Comment: Tried the code you suggested, but it didn't work.  Looking at the request with Fiddler I dont see the credentails sent...

Comment: Interesting note, the Uri I create use the following structure: "http://www.domain.com", trying to create a Uri without http:// prefix failed

Comment: Ah!!! I forgot the http in the URI ... It makes sense!!! It's a URI :P

Answer (score 0):

Plain text password is no longer a valid part of URL (according to respective RFC). You should be using `NetworkCredentials` as you already tried. See [MSDN for code snippet/sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(
    SecurelyStoredUserName,SecurelyStoredPassword,SecurelyStoredDomain);

CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();

myCache.Add(new Uri("http://www.contoso.com"), "Basic", myCred);
myCache.Add(new Uri("http://app.contoso.com"), "Basic", myCred);

WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
wr.Credentials = myCache;
```

UPD. Compared to MSDN code snippet, one needs to prefix strings with "http://" to avoid "Invalid URI" exception.

Comment: This throws a BAD URI Exception.