# Send login username with REST API + Powershell

Tags: rest, powershell, prestashop

I've got the following Powershell script:

```
$url = "http://somerandomapikeyhere@prestashop.dev/my-store/api"
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$response = $request.GetResponse()
echo $response
```

which attempts to access my Prestashop API REST service.

I can access the URL from Chrome without a problem, but in PowerShell I get a 401 Unauthorized response, which is understandeable as the **somerandomapikeyhere** bit in the URL needs to get dealt with differently in PowerShell.

The question is, how? Any ideas / advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not powershel, but the .net class that is not able to take an url in that format. You need to provide the credentials seperate. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508565/how-to-make-an-authenticated-web-request-in-powershell) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643746/create-a-httpwebrequest-for-a-http-userpassworddoamin-query-url).

But if you have powershell v3 you are better off using the build in commands for web requests or even REST requests.

```
Invoke-restmethod -uri 'prestashop.dev/my-store/api' -credential 'someapikey'
```

Comment: Ok, cool, I'm heading in the right direction. Just busy struggling getting SP1 on Win 7 so I can upgrade to PowerShell 3.0, as I understand 2.0 doesn't have the Invoke-RestMethod function.